# mac kernel panic; how can I read it?

Tags: macos, kernel, crash-dumps

I got the following kernel dump on Macbook Air.
Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5（11G63b）

My Mac is 64 bit version so the article https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2004/tn2118.html does not help me.

Kernel trap at 0xffffff80005e8124 so I want to find the module but the backtrace does not have any hint.

Could you help me?

```
Thu Feb 20 15:36:40 2014
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff80002c4794): Kernel trap at 0xffffff80005e8124, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0x0000000100000001, CR3: 0x0000000083201093, CR4: 0x00000000000606e0
RAX: 0xffffff80135aec00, RBX: 0xffffff80008df700, RCX: 0x0000000000000000, RDX: 0xffffff800ab05b88
RSP: 0xffffff80b03a3d30, RBP: 0xffffff80b03a3d50, RSI: 0x0000000000020002, RDI: 0x0000000100000001
R8:  0x0000000000000008, R9:  0xffffff80008bfaa0, R10: 0x0000000000000040, R11: 0xffffff80002dad60
R12: 0x0000000000000130, R13: 0xffffff800a571f80, R14: 0xffffff80116ca680, R15: 0x0000000000000013
RFL: 0x0000000000010282, RIP: 0xffffff80005e8124, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
CR2: 0x0000000100000001, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Faulting CPU: 0x2

Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff80b03a39e0 : 0xffffff8000220792 
0xffffff80b03a3a60 : 0xffffff80002c4794 
0xffffff80b03a3c10 : 0xffffff80002da55d 
0xffffff80b03a3c30 : 0xffffff80005e8124 
0xffffff80b03a3d50 : 0xffffff80005e85fd 
0xffffff80b03a3d80 : 0xffffff80005e8458 
0xffffff80b03a3de0 : 0xffffff800062010c 
0xffffff80b03a3e00 : 0xffffff80006227bb 
0xffffff80b03a3e10 : 0xffffff8000654d7b 
0xffffff80b03a3e50 : 0xffffff800029d8a5 
0xffffff80b03a3e80 : 0xffffff8000223096 
0xffffff80b03a3eb0 : 0xffffff80002148a9 
0xffffff80b03a3f10 : 0xffffff800021bbd8 
0xffffff80b03a3f70 : 0xffffff80002aef10 
0xffffff80b03a3fb0 : 0xffffff80002daec3 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: System Preferenc

Mac OS version:
11G63b

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 11.4.2: Thu Aug 23 16:25:48 PDT 2012; root:xnu-1699.32.7~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: FF3BB088-60A4-349C-92EA-CA649C698CE5
System model name: MacBookAir4,2 (Mac-742912EFDBEE19B3)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 324217868157493
last loaded kext at 4975708245448: com.apple.filesystems.smbfs  1.7.2 (addr 0xffffff7f80795000, size 241664)
last unloaded kext at 398561999464: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBUHCI       5.1.0 (addr 0xffffff7f80baa000, size 65536)
loaded kexts:
```

Comment: Did you truncate the log? The last line, "loaded kexts:", should have been followed by the information necessary to at least map from addresses to a kext.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. Yes, I cut the following log.
    loaded kexts:
    org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  4.2.12
    com.Symantec.kext.SAVAPComm     12.1
    org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  4.2.12
    org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB     4.2.12
    org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv     4.2.12
    com.checkpoint.kext.P4MacFilterScheme   1.0
    com.checkpoint.kext.FDECryptocore       1.0.0d1
    com.apple.filesystems.smbfs     1.7.2
    com.apple.driver.AppleIntelProfile      85.2
    com.apple.kext.mcx.alr  330
    ...

Comment: Hmm. I was expecting load addresses. If there aren't any, then I was wrong and that list doesn't help.